# "Dissect" object with generic type (uses lodash/mapValues)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wish to implement a generic function that accepts a typed object and returns one variation of that object ("dissected" by some key).

My MWE follows an example with breakpoints where i have a function that returns appropriate screen size properties from my config `responsiveObj`. For brevity the function is locked to `sm`, though my typing issue should be captured:

```
const responsiveObj = { firstItem, secondItem };
// Where
// (property) firstItem: Partial<Record<Breakpoints, PrimaryProps>>
// (property) secondItem: Partial<Record<Breakpoints, PrimaryProps & SecondaryProps>>

...

const responsiveFn = <T extends any, K extends keyof T>(
  responsive: Record<K, ResponsiveProps<UnknownGeneric>>
) => {
  // Dummy sm output
  const out = _.mapValues(responsive, (o) => {
    return { ...o.sm };
  });

  return out;
};

const result = responsiveFn(responsiveObj);

// Height is part of PrimaryProps and is identified
result.firstItem.height;

// Visible is part of SecondaryProps and is _not_ identified
result.secondItem.visible;
```

I want `SecondaryProps` to not get lost in the function.

Please see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-poc-vojjr) for full example.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3gyw) what you're looking for?  If so, I'm happy to write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please elaborate on the problem; ideally your [mcve] would not be dependent on any third-party libraries (like lodash) unless the question specifically has to do with those libraries or is tagged with them... so I replaced `_.mapValues` with a combination of `Object.fromEntries()`, `Object.entries()`, and an array `map()`.  Let me know.

Comment: Yes, @jcalz your answer solves my question. If you could elaborate that would be appreciated, I have some difficulty deciphering how it works.

Answer (score 0):

At the type level, what you're calling "dissection" seems to be something like the following:

- Start with am object type `T` with arbitrary property keys whose property values are some subtype of `ResponsiveProps`.
- For each property key `K` in `T`, the output object type will also have a property at key `K`.  So we want to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...}`
- For each property *value* type `T[K]`, which is some subtype of `ResponsiveProps`, the output property value type will be one of the property values at the `Breakpoints` keys.  That is, `T[K][Breakpoints]`.
- Note that this will quite possibly be `undefined` (since `ReponsiveProps` has all optional properties), but your output seems to produce an object even if the input does not exist (you are writing `{ ...(o.sm) }`, which will be `{}` if `o.sm` is `undefined`).  So we will want to specify use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to remove the possibility of `undefined` from the output type properties:

My inclination would therefore be to give `responsiveFn` a type signature like this:

```
/* const responsiveFn: <T extends Record<keyof T, ResponsiveProps>(
    responsive: T) => { [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K][Breakpoints]>; } */
```

Since your implementation is a "dummy" implementation that only pulls out the `sm` property, I have done the same thing here using `Object.entries()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, and `Object.fromEntries()`, instead of anything from lodash:

```
const responsiveFn = <T extends Record<keyof T, ResponsiveProps>>(
    responsive: T
): { [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K][Breakpoints]> } => {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(responsive).map(([
        k, v
    ]) => [k, { ...(v as any).sm }] as const)) as any;
};
```

Note that the compiler is not able to verify that the output value will conform to the annotated mapped type, so I use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `as any` to suppress compiler warnings.

---

If I use that version, this is what you get:

```
const result = responsiveFn(responsiveObj);
/* const result: {
    firstItem: PrimaryProps;
    secondItem: (PrimaryProps & SecondaryProps);
} */
console.log(result.firstItem.height) // 100
console.log(result.secondItem.visible) // false
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)